# Getting time out exception when trying to identify the webelemnt

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Below is the Code:

```
WebElement Username=d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']"));
Username.sendKeys("aadmin");

WebElement Password=d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_form']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[2]/input"));
Password.sendKeys("admin");

WebElement signin=d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit_']"));
signin.click();

System.out.println("User admin has logged in  "+ d1.getTitle());
w1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='spaces-menu']/ul/li[1]"))).click();

System.out.println("User Admin clicks on Record button");

//Thread.sleep(5000);
d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Switching the control
int size2=d1.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
System.out.println("iframe size is---" + size2);

WebDriverWait w2= new WebDriverWait (d1, 15);       
//w2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(0));
w2.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.tagName("iframe")));

System.out.println("Page title is     "+d1.getTitle());

//d1.switchTo().frame("iframe-page-container");

//d1.switchTo().frame(d1.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));

WebDriverWait w3= new WebDriverWait (d1,30);

WebElement New=w3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='capTypePopup']")));
    //WebElement New=w3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("menu-middle-normal-button")));
    //WebElement New=w3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menuButtonContain-6")));
    //New.click();

    //d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d1;
    //WebElement element = d1.findElement(By.id("menuButtonContain-6"));

    //js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', '')",element);

    //System.out.println(d1.findElement(By.id("menuButtonContain-6")).getAttribute("value"));


    //Actions a1= new Actions(d1);
    //a1.moveToElement(New).click(New).build().perform();

    //d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tr_menubar']/td"));
    //d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='capTypePopup']")).click();
    //w1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("portlet-menu-item"))).click();
    //w2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='capTypePopup']/font"))).click();
    System.out.println("Click on the new button");
```

Below is the DOM of the page, i am trying to click on New button which inside the iframe.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXelx.png)

Comment: This is error message that i am receiving, please help & suggest:Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@id='capTypePopup']
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'SandeepLT02', ip: '10.4.224.42', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Do you still get the error, when you try to explicitly switch to the frame 
d1.switchTo().frame(d1.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
and then perform the action. 
Does the error occur, even if you debug step-by-step? That might help you narrow down, if it is an issue with the wait or something else?

Comment: Your xpath is not correct , It finds multiple elements. I will suggest you have to find more unique xpath for your element

Answer (score 0):

The xpath:

`//div[@id='capTypePopup']`

you used will find more than one elements,selenium will use the first find element, which may be not the one your expected.

From your screenshot, i noticed there are already two, I guess there should be another one ahead of the div your desired and it's not visible.

Use `Dev` tool to test the `//div[@id='capTypePopup']`, and confirm the first found div is visible or not.

If not visible, use more strict xpath which can find the div you desired. After that your problem should gone.

Comment: Thank you for guidance but i have used below syntax also. Still getting error message.

Comment: WebDriverWait w3= new WebDriverWait (d1,30);
  
  WebElement New=w3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("portlet-menu-item")));